Can you switch your "Replicate Magic Item" Infusion after a long rest?
Say you originally had Goggles of night for your chosen Replicate Magic Item (RMI) Infusion for Artificer and you've only taken RMI once, after a long rest can you switch it to a Bag of holding if you're willing to give up the Goggles of Night that you infused previously?

No, you cannot.
The Replicate Magic Item feature says (emphasis mine):

Using this infusion, you replicate a particular magic item. You can learn this infusion multiple times; each time you do so, choose a magic item that you can make with it, picking from the Replicable Items tables.

You learn to replicate one single item: for example, if you are a 6th level Artificier you can learn Replicate Magic Item - Cloak of elvenkind. You can hence replicate the Cloak of elvenkind, but nowhere in the description of the feature it says that after a long rest you can switch on a different item, for example the Eyes of charming.
Once you learn this infusion, you can replicate only that particular item. As stated in the feature description, you can learn this infusion multiple times, each one for a different item.
Moreover, when you level up, you can

[...] replace one of the artificer infusions you learned with a new one.

So, in the previous example, you can substitute your Replicate Magic Item - Cloak of elvenkind with Replicate Magic Item - Eyes of charming.

Wow, yeah, my answer totally missed it.
